With or without an article
Is it grammatically correct to say this?

Shopping is women's leisure activity.

Or should I say this?

Shopping is a women's leisure activity.


You can say either, and they are equally sexist. For the #2 version, you need the singular: "Shopping is a woman's leisure activity." Still sexist.

Leaving out the article implies that it is the only leisure activity that women take part in - which isn't true!

Thank you for your answer! Actually, it's just an example. I can change it to men's leisure activity as well. I thought because of possessive s, I would remove 'a' from the sentence.

What @YosefBaskin said. It's more obvious if we compare Beans on toast is children's / a children's / a child's meal.

@FumbleFingers Good point about a children's meal.

I am very much a man, the last time I looked, and I love shopping, (or rather browsing, because I look much more than I buy). Sexist example.

I would be perfectly happy with either Beans on toast is a children's / child's meal, but not with Beans on toast is children's meal, as meal is countable. (Uncountable meal is ground grain.) However Beans on toast is children's / a child's food is fine, with food being uncountable. Activity might go either way, though I prefer the countable version.


Shopping is a women's leisure activity.

In American English, I would consider this to be the only correct answer.
In many cases, you can decide which form is correct by removing unnecessary words or clauses. In this case, if we remove the adjectives:

Shopping is activity
Shopping is a[n] activity

Since activity is a countable noun, it takes "a". If activity were instead uncountable, the first would be correct. Work is uncountable, so for instance:

Shopping is hard work!
(WRONG) Shopping is a hard work!

Sometimes the countability of a noun changes between American and UK English (math vs maths, sports vs sport), so it's possible that somewhere, activity is uncountable, in which case the former would be correct.
